# Using d3 in meteor on windows 8.1, how can I display a world map, zoomed in on the US, with country borders and US state borders?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, meteor

I'm writing something in meteor (in windows 8.1) and want to show a map, with the US states outlined, but the neighboring countries still showing.

[image: the basic map I want to show]

Ideally, the map would be an orthographic projection.

I also want to show points on the map, with text captions.

I tried putting [this tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/javascript/a-map-to-perfection-using-d3-js-to-make-beautiful-web-maps) into meteor, using [this topo.json file](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/raw/5189184/world-110m2.json) in my /public directory.

My html file is hello.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 World Map</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> map}}
</body>

<template name = "map">
    <div id="worldMap">
    </div>
</template>
```

my css file is hello.css:

```
path {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    fill: black;
}
```

and my js file is hello.js:

```
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
      });
    }


if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Template.map.rendered = function() {

          var width = 900;
          var height = 600;

          var projection = d3.geo.mercator();

          var svg = d3.select("#worldMap").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);
          var path = d3.geo.path()
              .projection(projection);
          var g = svg.append("g");


          // also tried d3.json("/world-110m2.json", function(error, topology)
          // "/public/world-110m2.json", and "public/world-110m2.json"
          d3.json("world-110m2.json", function(error, topology) { 
              g.selectAll("path")
                  .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
                      .geometries)
                  .enter()
                  .append("path")
                  .attr("d", path)
          });
      }
    }
```

My .meteor/versions file is:

```
autopublish@1.0.3
autoupdate@1.2.1
base64@1.0.3
binary-heap@1.0.3
blaze@2.1.2
blaze-tools@1.0.3
boilerplate-generator@1.0.3
callback-hook@1.0.3
check@1.0.5
d3@1.0.0
ddp@1.1.0
deps@1.0.7
ejson@1.0.6
fastclick@1.0.3
garrilla:topojson@1.6.18
geojson-utils@1.0.3
html-tools@1.0.4
htmljs@1.0.4
http@1.1.0
id-map@1.0.3
insecure@1.0.3
jquery@1.11.3_2
json@1.0.3
launch-screen@1.0.2
livedata@1.0.13
logging@1.0.7
meteor@1.1.6
meteor-platform@1.2.2
minifiers@1.1.5
minimongo@1.0.8
mobile-status-bar@1.0.3
mongo@1.1.0
observe-sequence@1.0.6
ordered-dict@1.0.3
random@1.0.3
reactive-dict@1.1.0
reactive-var@1.0.5
reload@1.1.3
retry@1.0.3
routepolicy@1.0.5
session@1.1.0
spacebars@1.0.6
spacebars-compiler@1.0.6
templating@1.1.1
tracker@1.0.7
ui@1.0.6
underscore@1.0.3
url@1.0.4
webapp@1.2.0
webapp-hashing@1.0.3
```

When I run it, it gives me 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <' tracing to line 1 of the rendered html file.

How can I get the map to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr : 
d3 in meteor on windows doesn't work for now, so run in ubuntu or mac

the d3 package is bad, do 'meteor add d3js:d3' instead

the meteor d3 is older, so use 'topojson.features', not 'topojson.objects'

Let me share with you how I solved this.  I was running meteor on windows, which is a problem because it doesn't seem like there is a d3 (or maybe topojson) package that works on windows (d3.json doesn't seem to be able to parse the json file, gives error of 'unexpected symbol at line 1 row 1 of json file').

It also seems like the d3 package isn't great, but the d3js:d3 package works.
Finally, it seems like the meteor d3js:d3 package is an older version of d3, for which you have to use 'topojson.features' instead of 'topojson.objects'.

So, after deploying in in ubuntu with those fixes, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The json files are fetched by url to `/data/geo/countries.topo.json`. Meteor matches the `/` path to the `/public` directory.

This means the json files are available in the `/public/data/geo` directory, or more specifically here: https://github.com/ArroyoLabs/meetups/tree/master/d3demo/public/data/geo